# Increase performance on Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing an application in that a list of images are fetched from firebase storage.

I am using blaze plan, however if I check performance rate in Firebase console,

it shows me

```
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*/o/*                   Success rate 52.49%
```

Like in below screenshot

[image]

It also shows me that **48% of request are failed**

[image]

Might be because of half the success rate I am getting negative reviews from different users.

How to increase performance?

Why does Google cloud have this 52% success rate instead of a more than 80% success rate?

Like I have array list of Firebase Storage URL and I am displaying URL into ImageView using Picasso

Like below code

```
 for(int i=0;i<urlList.size();i++){
            // Load those URL into ImageView using Picasso
 }
```

**This is not code related issue I am getting performance issue in Network**

Comment: It is impossible to say why your calls are failing without seeing the [minimal, complete/code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, first of thanks for your support but I am just loading image in ImageView using Picasso library.. I am passing Firebase storage URL which starts with https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/... What should I need to give more explanation?, just suggest me I am ready to post

Comment: We need to see whatever the code is that's failing and a better understanding of what your attempting to do. In other words, showing that it's failing in console doesn't give us any indication of *why* it's failing. We need to see code for that.

Comment: Why are you storing images in Firebase Storage, accessing the URL's From Firebase but *displaying URL into ImageView using Picasso*? The normal process is to access the URL from Firebase Real Time Database or Firestore, and then using those URL's, download the images from Storage to display in your ImageView. What does Picasso have to do with that process? As you can see, there's not enough info in the question to understand what's being done.

Comment: Hi jay... yes I am taking all URL from database then make arraylist and then use recycler adaptor to show all images using Picasso

Comment: I am first storing image in firebase storage then I have stored that image URL in firebase database and I am fetching those urls and then make a list and then I am passing those arraylist in recycler adaptor and then I am displaying image in recyclerview using Picasso